# How do you get a job at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have been a member here for almost half a year and have to say I love this community. I think it's an excellent resource for web development and programming. I am thoroughly impressed by how detailed and complex the software and framework is.

Earlier, I noticed an ad on Stack Overflow that said the company is hiring. I would really like to apply my talents to the company, and help them grow. It would be my way of giving back to the community.

I want to help improve their company. I would like to ask, has anyone here ever applied and gotten a job at Stack Overflow? If so, please share details about their hiring process.

Do they look at your Stack Overflow account, your reputation earned, your badges received? Do they look at other things?

Please answer this, because I truly am intrigued in working here, and helping the company grow.

I wish nothing but the best for this place.

Comment: I think following the blog and some announcements here is a good starting point. A while ago they were hiring someone who could speak Spanish to help manage an upcoming spanish version of SO.

Comment: [Check out this link](http://stackexchange.com/work-here)

Comment: This works the exact same way any USA company hires people.  You send your resume and a cover letter to the company, if they like what they see then they'll give you a call.

Comment: The way the mods on here get worked, I would suggest that a medical certification of insanity and alcoholism should be stapled to your CV.

Comment: @Martin - the message would be more effective if they were stapled to your forehead.

Comment: I wrote [a blog post](http://bretcope.blogspot.com/2013/07/theatre-kid-goes-to-stack-exchange.html) on how I got a job as a developer at Stack, if you're interested in hearing more about an individual journey.

Comment: @HansPassant In my experience, many high-end developer jobs are not gotten via applying cold, unless you already have some significant reputation in the field (in which you don't need to apply anyway, since every recruiter will be hitting on you). Networking is a much more important way to score the top jobs, which are often never advertised at all.

Comment: @HansPassant In fact I often write recruiters (the ones who write interesting emails, anyway) back saying that while I can't take up their offer (because it requires relocation, or it's in a field I don't care about, or...), if I know someone who's great for this, I'll let them know. (In truth, if I know someone who wants a job, I send them through _our_ recruitment system first (yay for referral bonuses ;-)), but if that doesn't work, I'll send them to the other recruiters in my contact list.)

Comment: @HansPassant In truth, if I refer someone, that carries a huge weight (I wouldn't refer them if I didn't think they were a good developer). So far, all the people I've made genuine referrals for have successfully been placed at our company. They are all highly esteemed members of our team who have each gone on to refer other great devs to our team. It's really a virtuous cycle. :-)

Answer (score 19):

You can apply to one of our [open positions](https://stackexchange.com/work-here).

Once you do, you will start on our interview process.

To get the job, you need to succeed in each step on the process ;)

---

The steps are generally as follows, for a developer position:

1. Initial screening of CV by our in house recruiter.
2. CV is screened by a developer.
3. Simple code screen.
   4-5. Harder code/architecture screens.
4. Interview with VP of engineering.

If one fails a step, they don't go to the next.

As far as I know, hiring on other teams follow a similar flow, focused on the team requirements (designers will design, sales people will be tested on sales knowledge/ability etc...).

Comment: I wonder whether having silly questions on your SO hinders you :')

Comment: @Stacker-flow - did you look at our [team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) page? You should see some of the questions those guys asked...

Comment: @Oded How do the interviews for remote workers go down? Obviously the process is very similar, but are some of the interviews held over Skype/Hangouts, or are they all in person, one way or another?

Comment: @Joe - I went through the process remotely. Interviews are held over Skype/Hangouts, coding done on a collaborative editor (different people have different preferences - google docs, collabedit and such). None were in person for me. Then again, if you are in NYC, you might be doing some in person.

Comment: Is the code screening live? I mean, do ten people stand behind you physically while coding? Just curious.

Comment: @phresnel - it is live, but usually done remotely. i.e. - you will be on a computer typing on a shared document (say, a Google doc), while the interviewer will also be looking at it. Both participants being on Google Hangouts or Skype or some such video conferencing software.